# Symfony2 disable cache for a specific bundle or route

Tags: symfony, caching, twig, sonata-admin

I have an issue with *Sonata Admin* Bundle that deleting (and maybe something else??) doesn't work when caching is on. It only works properly if I remove `$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);` from `app.php`.

How can I deactivate caching for *Sonata Admin*?

Comment: I also found out it's an issue and it should be fixed but I don't think disabling the cache is the best solution... Hopefully someone has a good idea how to fix it.

Comment: seems to be the right solution - the answer on my issue request https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1996

Comment: It's not a solution because I still have no clue how to exclude my admin urls...

Comment: you need a second frontend controller - like app.php but without caching

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Just add `Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();` after `$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);` and then DELETE methods will work.